# Save pictures from Android to Windows PC in DelphiXE5

Tags: android, windows, camera, delphi-xe5, datasnap

I have an **Android** application built in **DelphiXE5** which captures **pictures** from camera using the StandardAction **TTakePhotoFromCameraAction** of **TActionList**:

```
procedure TF_EdCamara.TakePhotoFromCameraAction1DidFinishTaking(Image: TBitmap);
begin
  { Assign the image retrieved from the Camera to the TImage component. }
  Image1.Bitmap.Assign(Image);
end;
```

Now, i need to store that **Image** from **Android** to a **Windows PC** via wireless.

¿How can I achieve this from **DelphiXE5**?

*Note: My app also uses **DataSnap/Rest** technology, therefore I could take advantage of it if necessary*

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Server-Side:

```
function TServerMethods.UploadImage(FileName: String; Stream: TStream): Integer;
const
  BufSize = $F000;
var
  Mem: TMemoryStream;
  BytesRead: Integer;
  Buffer: PByte;
begin
  try
    Mem := TMemoryStream.Create;
    GetMem(Buffer, BufSize);
    try
      repeat
        BytesRead := Stream.Read(Buffer^, BufSize);
        if BytesRead > 0 then
          Mem.WriteBuffer(Buffer^, BytesRead);
      until BytesRead < BufSize;
      // here, replace with DB update (if you want to save to DB)
      // for now, save to file
      Mem.Seek(0, TseekOrigin.soBeginning); // necessary?
      Mem.SaveToFile(FileName); //saves to current dir, you can have a parameter for expected directory otuput
      // ============================
      Result := 1; // Mem.Size doesn't work...
    finally
      FreeMem(Buffer, BufSize);
      Mem.Free;
    end;
  except
    Result := -1
  end;
end;
```

Client-Side:

```
procedure TClientModule.UploadBitmapByStream(Image: TBitmap; FileName: String);
var
  ImageStream: TMemoryStream;
  Bytes: Integer;
  FileName: String;
begin
  ImageStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Image.SaveToStream(ImageStream);
    ImageStream.Position := 0;        

    Bytes:= ServerMethods.UploadImage(FileName, ImageStream);
    if Bytes = -1 then
       raise Exception.create('Image transfer failed!')
  finally
    ImageStream.Free
  end;
end;
```

Then you can call

```
ClientModule.UploadBitmapByStream(Image1.Bitmap, 'File001.png');
```